# Highlight Panel Truncates Owner Lookup

Tags: lightning

Why when I put a highlight panel with the Owner field does it show only 3 characters? In the example document it shows 10 characters at least:

[image]

But here is my highlight panel note my name is only 8 characters long with a space:[image]

I've tried making it the only field and it still truncates it